# Problems determining image positioning using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

**Context:**

I have two images that I rotated 90 degrees (counterclockwise) and converted to PDF. I used two different tools to convert the images:

- Document A: Mac Preview
- Document B: ImageMagick

Visually, the documents appear exactly the same using a PDF client.

**Problem:**

I need to find the placement information of the images relative to the PDF page. My code correctly identifies the positioning for one document but is wrong for the other:

- Document A: Rectangle[x=792.0,y=0.0,w=614.4000244140625,h=792.0]
- Document B: Rectangle[x=0.0,y=0.0,w=792.0,h=614.4000244140625]

Visualizing the rectangle information, you can see that Document A (red) is not rotated and too far over on the x axis:

[image: Rectangle Positions]

**Details:**

Using the PDFBox debugger, I can see that Document A's image is rotated via CM operations:

```
q
Q
q
  /Perceptual ri
  q
    0 614.4 -792 0 792 0 cm
    /Im1 Do
  Q
Q
```

It appears that I'm not properly accounting for the rotation.

**Code:**

```
Matrix matrix = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
Rectangle2D.Double rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(
        matrix.getTranslateX(),
        matrix.getTranslateY(),
        matrix.getScalingFactorX(),
        matrix.getScalingFactorY()
);
```

**Attempted Solution**

Now I can get the rotation degrees from the matrix:

```
    protected int getRotation() {
        Matrix matrix = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
        double rotationRadians = -Math.atan2(matrix.getShearY(), matrix.getScaleY());
        return (int) Math.toDegrees(rotationRadians);
    }
```

And then rotate the rectangle:

```
    public Rectangle2D.Double rotate(Rectangle2D rectangle, int rotationDegrees) {
        double x = rectangle.getX() + rectangle.getWidth();
        double y = rectangle.getY();
        
        AffineTransform rotationTransform = new AffineTransform();
        rotationTransform.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotationDegrees), x, y);
        Shape rotatedRectangle = rotationTransform.createTransformedShape(rectangle);
        Rectangle2D bounds = rotatedRectangle.getBounds2D();
        return (Rectangle2D.Double) bounds;
    }
```

Now it's in the right orientation (green rectangle) but it needs to slide over:

[image: Rotated Rectangle Positions]

I could adjust the new rectangle's x positioning by subtracting the sum of the original and rotated widths. It feels like maybe I might start getting into brittle territory here. I also feel like I'm probably starting to re-invent a wheel.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

**Update:**

After further testing, this solution needs adjustments for other angles. I've handled 90, 180, 270. Thankfully we don't usually run across odd angles but I'm a bit concerned when we do.

Comment: *"I need to find the placement information of the images"* - what kind of *placement information* do you need? Would the coordinates of the 4 corners suffice?

Comment: Yeah, that's really all I need. Everything works well until the image has been rotated via CM operations.

Comment: I feel like I may have greatly over-complicated this because I missed something or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It's also a little hard to grok due to the inversion of the y axis and rotation degrees between Java and PDF.

Comment: Ah, right, in which coordinate system do you need those coordinates? The easiest to calculate coordinates would be the PDF user space coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you mentioned that *the coordinates of the 4 corners* would be *all you need*.

You can extract the default user space coordinates of the bitmap images used in a PDF by walking the page content stream instructions and, when finding a bitmap image drawing instruction, applying the then *current transformation matrix* to the corners of the unit square, (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), and (1, 1).

You can implement that using a specialized `PDFStreamEngine` like this:

```java
public class UserSpaceCoordinatesPrinter extends PrintImageLocations {
    public UserSpaceCoordinatesPrinter() throws IOException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void processOperator(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
        String operation = operator.getName();
        if (OperatorName.DRAW_OBJECT.equals(operation)) {
            COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get(0);
            PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject(objectName);
            if (xobject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                System.out.println("\nFound image [" + objectName.getName() + "]");
                Matrix ctm = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
                System.out.print("Corner coordinates in user space:");
                for (Vector corner : UNIT_SQUARE_CORNERS) {
                    System.out.print(" " + ctm.transform(corner));
                }
                System.out.println();
            } else if(xobject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
                PDFormXObject form = (PDFormXObject)xobject;
                showForm(form);
            }
        } else {
            super.processOperator(operator, operands);
        }
    }

    public static void print(PDDocument document) throws IOException {
        UserSpaceCoordinatesPrinter printer = new UserSpaceCoordinatesPrinter();
        int pageNum = 0;
        for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
            pageNum++;
            System.out.println("\n\nProcessing page: " + pageNum);
            System.out.println("Media box: " + page.getMediaBox());
            System.out.println("Page rotation: " + page.getRotation());
            printer.processPage(page);
        }
    }

    final static List<Vector> UNIT_SQUARE_CORNERS = List.of(
            new Vector(0, 0), new Vector(0, 1), new Vector(1, 0), new Vector(1, 1));
}
```

*([PrintImageCornerCoordinates](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox3/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox3/extract/PrintImageCornerCoordinates.java#L31C1-L74C1) utility class)*

You can use it like this:

```java
try (PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(PDF_SOURCE)) {
    UserSpaceCoordinatesPrinter.print(document);
}
```

*([PrintImageCornerCoordinates](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox3/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox3/extract/PrintImageCornerCoordinates.java#L85) test `testUserCoordinatesInput`)*

Comment: Perfect, much simpler. Thanks for pulling me out of the weeds!